# is @ObservedObject supported in xcode 12 in a MacOs app?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

[image: Error in macos swiftui xcode 12 app]

Is @ObservedObject supported in xcode 12 in a MacOs app? If not, any other way to do this? This is my first macos app...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move it out of the `body`, ie.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var net = Webservice()   // << here !!

    var body: some View {
    ...
    }
}
```